# Exceptions to sep = " " when reading table into R? Dealing with whitespace within fields

Tags: r, import

I need to import a table into R that is separated by spaces. Unfortunately, within some of the fields, there are spaces which cause R to separate into a new row. Is there any way of making those fields 'stick together'?

For example, the table looks like this:

```
V1    V2    V3    V4
Text  More  0.11  (a)kdfs hdfa ag$
Text  More  1.12  a
Text  More  0.21  v
Text  More  1222  (a)sdfs sdfa->g
Text  More  1232  (a)sdfs sdfa->g
```

But gets turned into this when R reads it (using `read.delim`)

```
V1    V2    V3    V4
Text  More  0.11  (a)kdfs 
hdfa  ag$
Text  More  1.12  a
Text  More  0.21  v
Text  More  1222  (a)sdfs 
sdfa->g
Text  More  1232  (a)sdfs 
sdfa->g
```

Those fields all have weird characters that aren't all shared with the other columns/rows. However, as seen, the spaces aren't flanked by the same characters.

In the original file, the rows are separated properly. Is there a way to do any of the following?

1. Stop separating by spaces after the fourth column is created
2. Have fields starting/ending with certain characters be stuck together as a string/add a non-space character where the spaces are
3. Generically, allow exceptions to `sep`

Quite new to R so sorry if this is very naive. Here is what my script looks like up to then:

```
strs <- readLines("file")
dat <- read.delim(text = strs, 
            skip = 17, 
            col.names = c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4"),
            sep = " ", header = F)
```

Is there anything I can add to either `read.delim` or `readLines` or in between those to fix this problem? As there is fluff that needs to be cut out (hence the `skip`) I can't use `read.table` (correct me if I'm wrong).

Some of the characters around the spaces are shared, so I would be willing to use a more tedious method to put other characters in place of the spaces in between e.g. 's' and 's'. Would that be possible with `gsub` if there isn't an easier method?

Thanks so much!

EDIT: Flash of insight, would it be possible to make the fourth column a new table (that's of course not separated by spaces), then replace all spaces in that table with something else? How would I go about 'breaking off' the fourth column/columns after the third column?

Comment: If I were you I would tackle the problem at the root. This is not an acceptable format to work with, so tell whoever created the file to enclose values within quotes, or use a different separator.

Comment: I would, but unfortunately a) it's output from a computational model and b) I have several files (>15) that I need to work with and I can't go in individually to change it or ask anyone else to.

Comment: some reading: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delimiter_collision#Delimiter_collision

Comment: Does every field have a [fixed-width](http://databasesuperstar.com/ms-access-tutorial-fixed-width-text-file/)? If so, `read.fwf` could be a solution.

Comment: @BlueMagister Nope, although I could have made it so I suppose, by adding an extra character to certain strings... anyway the answer solved it so hooray!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1)** Try this:

```
for(i in 1:3) strs <- sub(" +", ",", strs)
read.csv(text = strs)
```

The result of the last line is:

```
    V1   V2      V3               V4
1 Text More    0.11 (a)kdfs hdfa ag$
2 Text More    1.12                a
3 Text More    0.21                v
4 Text More 1222.00  (a)sdfs sdfa->g
5 Text More 1232.00  (a)sdfs sdfa->g
```

**2)** Here is a second solution:

```
strs.comma <- sub("^(\\S+) +(\\S+) +(\\S+) +", "\\1,\\2,\\3,", strs)
read.csv(text = strs.comma)
```

Comment: It worked! (The first solution, have yet to try the second) Amazing! Thank you so much.